# Passport MRZ code can't be detected by Ml Kit?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am using this part of code for detection but whatever I do it can't detect Machine Readable Zone (MRZ).

```
    String recognizedText = firebaseVisionCloudText.getText();

for (FirebaseVisionCloudText.Page page: firebaseVisionCloudText.getPages()) {
    List<FirebaseVisionCloudText.DetectedLanguage> languages =
            page.getTextProperty().getDetectedLanguages();
    int height = page.getHeight();
    int width = page.getWidth();
    float confidence = page.getConfidence();

    for (FirebaseVisionCloudText.Block block: page.getBlocks()) {
        Rect boundingBox = block.getBoundingBox();
        List<FirebaseVisionCloudText.DetectedLanguage> blockLanguages =
                block.getTextProperty().getDetectedLanguages();
        float blockConfidence = block.getConfidence();
    }
}
```

Is it possible that it can't read the font? If so is there an option to add font?
Also is it possible to combine Ml Kit with Tesseract?

Comment: can you try the quick starter app I linked below and let me know how that works out?

Comment: Did you manage to get M kit working in order to scan MRZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is it possible that it can't read the font?*

It is possible. That said, things like Driver licenses work for Text recognition with ML Kit. Have you tried running the [quick starter app](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit)  or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#0) on your use case?

*is there an option to add font?*

You cannot add it directly. We will have to update the model with that font. If your use case does not work out, please feel free to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) and we will be happy to understand your use case and update the model.

*Also is it possible to combine Ml Kit with Tesseract?*

Definitely. You will have to do it yourself though outside of the ML Kit API call.

Comment: I'm able to extract all text but how can I extract specific text from driving licence like name, dob, address etc?

Comment: @VikashParajuli: Did u got any solution on this?